# .htaccess Apache core:error 20023 20024

Tags: apache-2.4, .htaccess

Apache 2.4 default settings, OS 7
Without .htaccess, the site works fine. URL string contains localized characters. I create an .htaccess file strictly according to the instructions, to make a short URL. and i have few errors on loading page:

```
(20023)The given path was above the root path: AH00127: Cannot map GET /%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0 HTTP/1.1 to file
(20023)The given path was above the root path: AH00127: Cannot map GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1 to file, referer: http://ru.techwik.org/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0
```

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} !-f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/index.php [L]
```

I could not find a clear answer or do not understand something. Firstly, it is not clear why such a simple rule that I took from few the  instructions does not work? Why doesn't the internal redirect to index.php work? How to fix?
And secondly, why doesn't work RewriteRuke with localized escaped pages? (error 20024) Can this be fixed somehow?

Comment: Regarding "error 20024", what URL are you requesting that results in this error? (Maybe it relates to the earlier issue?) I can't reproduce this with the encoded URLs given.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/index.php [L]
> ```

You can only rewrite to an absolute filesystem path in a *server* (or *virtualhost*) context. In `.htaccess` it is a URL-path, relative to the document root (when prefixed with a slash). (What response is being received in the browser? A 403?)

So, in `.htaccess`, this directive should be written:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php [L]
```

Or, omit the slash prefix altogether (ie. `index.php`), so that is it relative to the directory of the `.htaccess` file (unless a `RewriteBase` states otherwise).

*Aside:* There is no need to have a capturing backreference in the `RewriteRule` *pattern* (ie. `(.*)`). The regex `^(.*)$` traverses the entire URL-path and saves this for use later (as a `$1` backreference). If you simply want to match *anything* (rather than *everything*) then use `^` (start of string anchor) or `.?` (an optional character) or `$` (end-of-string-anchor). Although you can avoid the unnecessary filesystem checks when requesting the document root by checking for `.` (an single character). For example:

```
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

This does assume that `index.php` is defined as the `DirectoryIndex`.

Comment: Excellent! But: /Page - Ok /index.php/Test - Ok /index.php?title=Test&action=edit - Ok /index.php/Some:Page - Ok /Some:Page - unfortunately - You don't have permission to access

Comment: On Windows, a colon (`:`) in the first URL-path segment will result in such an error. This is unfortunately a limitation of Apache on Windows. It's not a problem on Linux. If the colon appears later in the URL-path it's OK. eg. `/anypath/Some:Page`. (Incidentally, your 3 tests that include `/index.php` in the requested URL will bypass these directives.)

Comment: / index.php/Some:Page - it works, and everything is satisfactory to me. With Linux will work. The problem is solved.